# Loading a pre-trained model to a python script

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pickle

I have to load a pretrained model to a python script for evaluation. I have tried to do it by saving the model to a pickle file and accesing it through a url (of the repo it is hosted at) and then unplickling it. However, I get an invalidkey error. Any ideas on how I could solve it?

code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import random
import pickle
from PIL import Image
import urllib

class Model():
    def load_model(self, url):
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        with open('cnn.pkl', "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.read())

    def predict(self, file_path):
        self.load_model('https://github.com/JuanRuedz/Rice-classification-model/blob/48ead0817e633e5f5e295636e7960182119d72cd/cnn.pkl')
        img = Image.open(file_path)
        img = np.array(img)
        img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
        with open("cnn.pkl", "rb") as f:
            mod = pickle.load(f) 
        pred = mod.predict(img)
        index = np.where(pred[0] == 1)[0][0]
        return index
```

Comment: Maybe you can try using the code that is generated https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com but that requires your model to be stored as a .h5 file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format the code properly. Use the preview.

Comment: @ThomasWeller already did, thanks! :)

Comment: @NedHulton its okay if the model is saved on a h5 file. as long as i can access it through a url it is okay. I will try it, thanks!

Comment: You need to include the full error message verbatim.

Comment: Hey everyone, solved the error. I just used a keras builtin function to save the model as a hd5 file. Then i uploaded the file to a git repo and accessed it using model = keras.models.load_model(URL). Turns out new versions of keras support accesing models through URL. If you are using an old keras version then there are extra steps but still possible (I used tensorflow 2.9 and keras 2.9).

Answer (score 0):

For the community benefit, Posting the resolution in the answer section as mentioned by user **@Juan_Ruedz**.

> I just used a keras builtin function to save the model as a hd5 file.
> Then i uploaded the file to a git repo and accessed it using `model = keras.models.load_model(URL)`. Turns out new versions of keras support
> accesing models through URL. If you are using an old keras version
> then there are extra steps but still possible (I used **tensorflow 2.9**
> and **keras 2.9**).